# JQuery slider event triggered on individual handle (slider range)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, slider, jquery-events

Is there a way to trigger events based on the movement of individual slider handles?

It would be interesting as I need to update a datepicker depending of the handle moved. The problem is that I don't know if there's actually a way:

- To specify an event on a specific handle
- Or to retrieve the id of the moved handle via a listener...

Here's how my events are currently triggered.

```
$(function() {
      var evt = this.timelineDiv
        .children(".slider")
        .slider({
          min: this.dates.start,
          max: this.dates.end,
          step: 1,
          change: function(event, ui) {
            conditionalDatePickersUpdate();
            },
          slide: function(event, ui) {
            conditionalDatePickersUpdate();
            }
          })
          .slider("pips", {
            rest: "label",
            step: 1
            })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly; 
your setup indicates only a single handle. For multiple handles you'd need to have `values: Array` set as an option.

Secondly; 
You may use the built-in `ui` object to check the handleIndex, and the value.

```
$(function(){
  var values = [1,10];
  var $slider = $(".slider").slider({ 
    values: values, 
    change: handleChanged 
  }).slider("pips");

  // fill in the rest of your setup

});
```

And then after the change event triggers you may compare the values to the original with the following method;

```
var handleChanged = function( evt, ui ) {
  switch ( ui.handleIndex ) {
    case 0:
      // do something for first handle
      break;
    case 1:
      // do something for second handle
      break;
    case 2:
      // do something for third handle
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: You can learn about the change-event from the jQueryUI API page; https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

Comment: Thanks ! It works great ! Sorry, I put the prototype to create the slider, it actually is updated depending on the user's choice.